# if Statement, node js/ JavaScript.. how do I output to the console the rules that are declared in the provided code only if it’s Sunday?

Tags: javascript

```js
function main() {
    var dayofWeek = readLine();
    var quietRules = 'mowing, hanging out laundry, washing a car, recycling bottles are not allowed';
    if (dayofWeek) {
        console.log('mowing, hanging out laundry, washing a car, recycling bottles are not allowed');
    }
```

Comment: Reading up on the [if statement docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and the [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) operator should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

```
switch (dayOfWeek) {
   case "Sunday":
      console.log('mowing, hanging out laundry... etc')
   case "Monday":
      console.log('make coffee, commute to work... etc')
   default:
      console.log('wake up, eat')
}
```

Note the default case is like the "else" of a switch statement.

There's another way to do it, by structuring your "rules" variable around day of the week.

```
var quietRules = {
   "Sunday": "mowing, hanging out etc..."
   "Monday": "working, excercise"
}
if(dayOfWeek) {
  console.log(quietRules[dayOfWeek])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check the document, but, there is a simple example.

```
if(dayofWeek === "Sunday")
{
console.log('mowing, hanging out laundry, washing a car, recycling bottles are not allowed');
}
```